# ReactJS: How to render rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, fetch-api

I am facing an issue to order the rows of a fetched API data dynamically, i.e if the rows data within the API is changed (+/- row) to render it automatically. I am trying to print the data fetched from an API into a table. Anyhow the columns are well printed dynamically, but the function that I am using for columns this.state.columns.map(( column, index ) => doesn't function in the same way for the rows. I think i am misleading the ES6 standard, but I am not sure. [Here is how it's look like, if the rows are not hardcoded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv0br.jpg)

Here is my code sample:

```
class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            rows: [],
            columns: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {

        fetch( "http://ickata.net/sag/api/staff/bonuses/" )
            .then( function ( response )
            {
                return response.json();
            } )
            .then( data =>
            {
                this.setState( { rows: data.rows, columns: data.columns } );
            } );

    }

    render()
    {

        return (
            <div id="container" className="container">
                <h1>Final Table with React JS</h1>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr> {
                            this.state.columns.map(( column, index ) =>
                            {
                                return ( <th>{column}</th> )
                            }
                            )
                        }
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> {
                        this.state.rows.map(( row ) => (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{row[0]}</td>
                                <td>{row[1]}</td>
                                <td>{row[2]}</td>
                                <td>{row[3]}</td>
                                <td>{row[4]}</td>
                                <td>{row[5]}</td>
                                <td>{row[6]}</td>
                                <td>{row[7]}</td>
                                <td>{row[8]}</td>
                                <td>{row[9]}</td>
                                <td>{row[10]}</td>
                                <td>{row[11]}</td>
                                <td>{row[12]}</td>
                                <td>{row[13]}</td>
                                <td>{row[14]}</td>
                                <td>{row[15]}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ) )
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render( <div id="container"><App /></div>, document.querySelector( 'body' ) );
```

Instead, I was able to print the rows harcoded, if I give value to the 'td' elements, but I want to print it dynamically, in case the data within the API has been changed.

You are welcome to contribute directly to my Repo: [Fetching API data into a table](https://github.com/andimit/fetching-react-api)

[Here is how looks like my example, when the rows values has been hardcoded within 'td' elements.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvTi6.jpg)

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you are iterating over columns and rows you could add an additional loop for iterating over row cells.
For example:

```
this.state.rows.map(row => (
  <tr>{row.map(cell => (
    <td>{cell}</td>
   ))}
  </tr>
))
```

Note that you probably want to add a [key prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity

Comment: Hey @Craig Ayre what a fast shot, thanks a lot! You have a beer or two from me! :)